# Undesired data insertion to database

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

An employee can claim the amount of money spent on official duty from the employer.

I am working on a website in which after a staff filled in the official duty activity (details), staff is then shown a dynamic form in which they can add/remove transport/meal/hotel claim, depending on how long (days) it takes to complete the duty. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10I2K.jpg) is the design I came up with.

Here is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loHw5.jpg) . TransportID 8 & 9 should be in the same row as activityID 11. Is there a way to insert > 1 primary keys into a field?

```
foreach ( $_POST["dates"] as $index=>$date ) {
$origin = $_POST["origins"][$index];
$destination = $_POST["destinations"][$index];
$cost = $_POST["costs"][$index];

    //Insert into transport table
    $sql_transport1 = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_transport (Date, Origin, Destination, Cost) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s')",
        mysql_real_escape_string($date),
        mysql_real_escape_string($origin),
        mysql_real_escape_string($destination),
        mysql_real_escape_string($cost));
        $result_transport1 = $db->query($sql_transport1);
        $inserted_transport_id1 = $db->last_insert_id();

    //Insert into transport_mainclaim table
    $sql_transport_mainclaim1 = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_transport_mainclaim (claimID, transportID) VALUES ('%s','%s')",
        mysql_real_escape_string($inserted_mainclaim_id1),
        mysql_real_escape_string($inserted_transport_id1));
        $result_transport_mainclaim1 = $db->query($sql_transport_mainclaim1);

    $all_transport_id = implode(",",$inserted_transport_id1);

    //Insert into mainclaim table
    $sql_mainclaim = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_mainclaim (activityID, transportID, IC) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')",
        mysql_real_escape_string($inserted_activity_id), 
        mysql_real_escape_string($all_transport_id),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['IC']));
        $result_mainclaim = $db->query($sql_mainclaim);
        $inserted_mainclaim_id = $db->last_insert_id(); 
}
```

I have tried using `$all_transport_ID = implode(",",$inserted_transport_id1);`to separate IDs with comma but failed to do so.

Is the database structure wrongly designed?  Please guide me as I want to get this right.

Comment: This won't fix your problem but you should use `mysqli_` and not the deprecated `mysql_`

Comment: I'm aware of that, but this is something that I want to do.

Comment: May I know why ? There is literally 0 reason not to switch to `mysqli_`. You could also use `PDO` or `Doctrine DBAL` or anything over `mysql_`.

Comment: By the time I found out it's deprecated, I have already learned the basics of mysql. So I proceed on, however, the aim is to learn something new after I'm done with this project.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I couldn't comment on your post because of reputation but I think you gave the wrong link. Your code is operating on table tbl_transport whereas the link you gave shows table named tbl_mainclaim.

Regardless of that,you are trying to insert two integer values 8 and 9 in the column of integer type on the same row as activity id with int value 11. How are you planning to store that?

UPDATE: I think the way which you are implementing this code is wrong. If i am correct your variable `$inserted_transport_id` is an array whereas in this line you are treating it as a variable. `$inserted_transport_id1 = $db->last_insert_id();`

As you are using implode which combines array into a string , here you are treating it as an array.

```
$all_transport_id = implode(",",$inserted_transport_id1);
```

So I am not sure what you are trying to implement. Its not clear what you are trying to do with that foreach loop for whole SQL.

And if your application permits, you can remove tbl_transport_mainclaim,tbl_meal_mainclaim,tbl_hotel_mainclaim and directly assign foreign key of the tables tbl_transport,tbl_hotel,tbl_meal which references to the respective columns on the tbl_mainclaim.

I might be able to help you with your further explaination about what you are trying to implement in this page.

Comment: Code updated, I tried using implode() to store the int values, but it's not working.

Comment: implode() returns string whereas the TransportId column in your database table is of interger type. Did you try fixing that?

Comment: No, I wasn't aware implode() returns only string. Any ideas on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Don't escape `$all_transport_id`; do escape (or verify that they are numeric) the values in `$inserted_transport_id1`.

In the future, do this to help with debugging:

```
echo $sql_mainclaim;
```